# Host an apk app to the public using public url

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, apk, devops, amazon-route53

I wanted to have a Public download url to download an apk app currently hosed on github. I'm normally used to deploying microservices to aws using bitbucket, Jenkins and EKS and expose the services to the public using k8s services and route 53 but I've never hosted an apk file. Anyone who can help me how I can have a public url that users can use to download the app?

Comment: Put it to Play Store maybe?

Comment: You can use Netlify or Github Page to have direct link to that APK file. But it is a bad idea to store APK in Github because its upload speed too slow.

Comment: would Netlifly allow me to have a public URL?